# Rails. Development.log size exceeded. Git not pushing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
 $ ruby -v
 ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]
 $ rails -v
 Rails 4.2.4
```

I am using Cloud9 community workspace.
when i pushing to git it throws error

> ERROR: File log/development.log is 101.06 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB

but when i check file it shows its size as 0 bytes. i deleted file also. still git shows same error . it doesn't work for me.

and also I could not found proper solution for **how to install git-lfs on cloud9.**

Kindly help me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

you should exclude your log folder from git.

Make sure you have file named .gitignore in the root of your project and inside of the file you list your directories you want to exclude:

```
/log/*
/tmp
```

then you can remove your files from git by running in terminal in the project folder:

```
git rm cached ./log/*
```

than commit and try again

Comment: what if you reinitialize your repository? copy project over and on the copy remove hidden .git  folder and re-initialize repo `git init` and `git add .` `git commit -m "initial commit"` and try to deploy this. make sure your dont do it on your main project but on the copy. when you remove .git folder you basically loose your git history

Comment: is there any way to install git lfs on cloud9? if not i will try as u mentioned

Answer (score 1):

i have 8 unpushed commits. i removed them by executing below code

```
git reset HEAD~8
```

and also i made ignore log files using 
[gitignore.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/gitignore)